# java Pattern Matching issue

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an issue to write proper regex to match URL.

```
String input = "AAAhttp://www.gmail.comBBBBabc@gmail.com"    
String regex = "www.*.com"  // To match www.gmail.com URL    
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex)
Matcher m = p.matcher(input)
while(m.find()){

}
```

Here I want to remove the Url `www.gmail.com`. However it matches till end of string to match  email address also which ends with `gmail.com`. 
Can someone help me to get proper regex to match only the URL?

Comment: _Here I want to remove the Url `www.gmail.com`_ are you sure or you want to extract????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` does a greedy match. You have to add `?` after `*` to does an reluctant match.

```
"www\\..*?\\.com"
```

Your code would be,

```
    String s = "AAAhttp://www.gmail.comBBBBabc@gmail.com";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("www\\..*?\\.com");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/J45mEN)

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "www\\..*?\\.com"
```

Non-greedy repetition of the wildcard '.' and escape dot when literally

Answer (score 0):

**A negated character class is faster than `.*?`**

Use this regex:

```
www\.[^.]+\.com
```

`[^.]+` means any character that is not a dot.

**In Java we need to escape some characters:**

```
// for instance
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("www\\.[^.]+\\.com");
// etc
```